# Checkpoint beginner

Tags: firewall, checkpoint

My company got few CP firewalls, I have to test them and I never had a chance to work on them.

Can anyone explane me differences between CP smart dashboard and CP smart console?

Is that software free?

I want to configure my device from Url https://my_device:4433, but every guide I saw explane configuration from CP dashboard or console?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Check Point management architecture

Check Point management is a bit different when you're used to other firewall products. Regardless of whether you have a single firewall or whether you're managing dozens fo different appliances, you always use a management server and a (trusted) GUI client. Check this picture from [a CCSA introduction blogpost](https://injectorcode.blogspot.com/2016/09/ccsa-checkpoint-introduction-01.html):
[image: Check Point management architecture]

When you only have one appliance, you can run the "Management Server" on the same box as the "Security Gateway" (the firewall itself), but more comonly you install the management server on a VM. You can get the software from the [Check Point website](https://downloads.checkpoint.com/dc/filedetails.htm?ID=77093&product=1025&version=R80&os=Gaia&appID=4).

All modern Check Point appliances have a webinterface, but you cannot use that to manage firewall policies. You only use that to configure device-specific settings like interfaces, routing, time, SNMP, etc. All policies relating to traffic passing through the box (firewall, NAT, VPN, ...) is configured through the management server.

### Check Point clients

In previous versions of the Check Point software, they had a whole bunch of [different GUI clients](http://what-when-how.com/check-point-ng-vpn-1firewall-1/smartdashboard-smart-clients-check-point-part-1-2/): SmartDashboard to manage policies, SmartViewTracker to view logfiles, SmartViewMonitor for realtime monitoring, and some more specialized tools too.

Since R80 Check Point is trying to consolidate all these tools in a single new GUI client: SmartConsole. They are mostly succeeding, mostly...

You can download the correct version of SmartConsole directly using the webinterface of your Security Management Server, or you can try the [Check Point download center](https://supportcenter.checkpoint.com/supportcenter/portal?eventSubmit_doGoviewsolutiondetails=&solutionid=sk137593).